# Read quoted items with spaces into array

Tags: arrays, bash

Say I have the file `foo.txt`

```
"The" "quick brown" "fox" "jumps over" "the" "lazy dog."
```

I would like to read these "fields" from the file into an array. However my attempt is failing if the field has a space

```
$ read -a bar < foo.txt

$ echo ${bar[0]}
"The"

$ echo ${bar[1]}
"quick
```

I have seen answers suggest changing `IFS`, but this is a single line so that would appear not to help.

Comment: "I have seen answers suggest changing `IFS` ..." Then you have badly misinterpreted what those questions are asking in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function that will do the job. It might be slow for huge strings, but will do the job all right, with no caveats like arbitrary code execution or path name expansion:

```
#!/bin/bash

parse_quoted_items() {
    # Return array is parse_quoted_items_ary
    local line=$1
    parse_quoted_items_ary=() parse_quoted_items_error=
    while [[ $line ]]; do
        if [[ $line =~ ^[[:space:]]*\"([^\"]*)\"([[:space:]]+.+|)[[:space:]]*$ ]]; then
            parse_quoted_items_ary+=( "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" )
            line=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        else
            parse_quoted_items_error=$line
            return 1
        fi
    done
}
```

Then you can use as

```
IFS= read -r line < foo.txt
if parse_quoted_items "$line"; do
    declare -p parse_quoted_items_ary
else
    printf >&2 "There was an error parsing the string at %s\n" "$parse quoted_items_error"
    exit 1
fi
```

This is not a satisfactory answer, but I doubt there are any (safe) ways that don't explicitly parse the string.

Answer (score 1):

`IFS` won't help. This works:

```
eval bah=(`cat foo.txt`)
```

Test:

```
for i in "${bah[@]}"; do echo $i; done
```

Comment: This is subject to arbitrary code execution, pathname expansion and other caveats, e.g., with a string like `"The quick *" "brown $(ls)" [10]=lol`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Thats true. If you did not trust the source of the file - as in for example you did not generated it, you'd have to parse it first of course. Still its the simplest, most straight forward solution so is worth noting.

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl:

```
IFS=$'\n' a=( $(perl -ne '@a = split (/("[^"]*")/); for (my $i=1; $i<@a; $i+=2) { print "$a[$i]\n" }' foo.txt) )
```

Note: this will be slower than a pure bash solution since it has to start up the Perl interpreter.

**Update:**

For Bash 4+: To avoid setting `IFS` globally:

```
readarray -t a < <(perl -ne '@a = split (/("[^"]*")/); for (my $i=1; $i<@a; $i+=2) { print "$a[$i]\n" }' foo.txt)
```

Comment: In Bash≥4 you can replace the `IFS=$'\n' a=( $(perl ...) )` by `mapfile -t a < <(perl ...)`, so that you don't set `IFS` globally. It'll be better too as it won't be subject to filename expansions.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Thanks, answer updated.. I think filename expansion is not the case in either case..

Comment: @HåkonHægland, you might take a look at my solution. ;) It took me a long time to figure out how to propery redirect the output but it's quite similar to yours. I found it too bad to discard everything after spending so much time to find out whats wrong with piping.

Comment: @HåkonHægland Without `mapfile`, pathname expansion occurs, e.g., `touch '"hello"'` and with `foo.txt` having an item like this: `"*"`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Strange, it does not happen for me. I just get the literal `"*"` as an element in the `a` array.. (using the first approach with `IFS` and without `mapfile`)

Comment: Did you really put quotes around hello? The file need to be called `"hello"` (quotes included). Also (and separately) you may try with `shopt -s nullglob` or `shopt -s failglob`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Yes you are right.. this is funny. The `*` gets expanded if the file name has quotes like `"hello"`. Then I have learnt something today also :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is similar to Håkon Hægland's:

It also uses Bash's [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) and [`readarray`/`mapfile`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-readarray) but the Perl part is a bit shorter.

```
readarray -t words < <(cat fox.txt | perl -i -pe 's/(?<=") (?=")/\n/g')
```

or just

```
readarray -t words < <( perl -pe 's/(?<=") (?=")/\n/g' fox.txt )
```

The line is processed using Perl substituion utilizing lookbehind and lookahead to detect the spaces following a `"` and being followed by another `"`. These spaces are replaced with newlines to allow `readarray` to read each line into the array `words`. This multiline output is then passed into `readarray`, `-t` will strip off the trailing newlines before adding them to the array.

---

Note while testing this I had trouble naively piping the output of `perl` directly to `readarray`, it appeared never to read a line into the array, since it was empty. As @gniourf_gniourf pointed out this has todo with the fact that the right hand programs are started in a subshell "binding" any variable created within that subshell.

Related resource:

["I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)

Interesting.

Comment: Nice one.. Regarding the use of `cat` and pipe: It is not necessary, use `readarray -t a < <(perl -pe 's/(?<=") (?=")/\n/g' foo.txt)`

Comment: Your note might be completely wrong: if you do `perl ... | mapfile` then `mapfile` will run in a subshell and so the array will only be set for this subshell. When the command exits and the subshell closes, all is gone! That's why you need process substitution. Also see [BashFAQ/024](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024). By the way, your `-n0` is useless, but your command is missing `-t`.

Comment: You're right `-t` is a good option to remove the newlines. `-n0` was kind of cargo cult. ;) Thanks for pointing out why the variable is empty and that it's not related to buffering. I'll update my post!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ . <(sed 's/^/set /' foo.txt)

$ echo $1
The

$ echo $2
quick brown
```

Comment: If you are looking to get the values into an array: `. <(sed 's/^/set /' foo.txt); myarray+=( "$@" )` will do the trick.

Comment: But you clobber your positional parameters.

Comment: This is subject to arbitrary code execution: `"The quick $(ls)"`.